# Modify fields in embedded iframe on remote server

Tags: jquery, iframe, hubspot

I have a site, and we're using an embedded iFrame from Hubspot, and I need to be able to access the form elements and make some adjustments with jquery or plain javascript.

In the source, I can find the iframe, and then trying to access the "email" element and set some attributes (can't do it in Hubspot itself).

It's hosted on Hubspot, so I'm not sure I can do this, but if I can, does anyone know how?